# C++ ostream fill adding a trailing 0

Tags: c++, ostream, setw

Hello I am having an issue formatting my output using the ostream object in C++.

```
ostream& write(ostream& os)
{
    os << os.fill('*') << os.width(10);
    return os;
}
```

This is what the output looks like:

```
********* 0
```

I'm trying to achieve 10 `*`s without the trailing `0`.

What is the cause of the trailing `0`?

Am I using width and fill functions incorrectly?

Comment: Isn't it a *trailing 0*?

Comment: Pop quiz: Part 1: what is the value of the following expression: `os.fill('*')`, what does this expression evaluate to. Part 2: what happens if you write the value of this expression, using the overloaded `<<` operator, to a `std::ostream` object?

Comment: @NickyC Yes it is my bad.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I will try that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it says in [`ios::base::width`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios_base/width/) :

> Return value : The value of the field width before the call.

So what you are doing is `fill` your `ostream` with `*`s and then print the value of the field before call which is `0`.

And there is another thing that you probably didn't notice that before `0`, you have another char, that's because of [`std::ios::fill`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/fill/) return value :

> Return value : The value of the fill character before the call.

Try this :

```
ostream& write(ostream& os)
{
    os.fill('*');
    os.width(10);
    return os;
}
```

Comment: Or, use I/O manipulators instead of calling the stream methods directly: `return os << std::setfill('*') << std::setw(10);`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Actually that's a better idea, I will upvote it if you post it as answer.

Comment: Just to make sure I've got this right. By doing os << os.fill and os <<os.width as adding their return value into the output stream. and os.fill() and os.width() is setting the correct properties inside the object without directly effecting the output stream?

Comment: @Devin Yes, this way you don't add their return value to your `ostraem`. They just do their job and their return value will be ignored.